# sequential continuity and continuity

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, continuity, locally-compact-groups

When we have two topological spaces, $(X, \tau_X)$ and $(Y, \tau_Y)$ it is easy to check that for $f: X \rightarrow Y$ continuity implies sequential continuity. I'm wondering what do we have to assume for $X$, $Y$ for the converse to hold: here, [sequential continuity vs. continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853208/sequential-continuity-vs-continuity), are given two sufficient properties ($X$ being sequential, $X$ being first countable). Can it be switched with something else? In particular I'm interested if it holds when $X$ is locally compact and Hausdorff, $Y=\mathbb{K}\in \{ \mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$.

I'd like just a hint, not full proof.

Comment: I don't think so. Sequential spaces are pretty much defined to be the weakest spaces where such a condition holds. $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ in the product topology is compact and Hausdorff, but is not sequential. See this: http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1164&context=math

Comment: Thank You.  I don't really see why is it sequential though. I've tried to show that $\left( \prod_{t \in [0,1]}]\frac{1}{2},1]\right)' $ is sequentially closed but it doesn't seem to be the case.